# Rails 3 - trying to create polymorphic has_one association in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, rails-console

Here's my code:

Models:

```rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :author, :content, :imageable_attributes

  has_one :image, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image, allow_destroy: true

  validates_presence_of :title, :content, :author
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  attr_accessible :image, :caption, :imageable_id, :imageable_type, :article_ref

  validates_presence_of :image
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Here's what I've tried in console:

```rb
article = Article.create!(title: "test", content: "test", author: "test", image_attributes: {image: "test.jpg", caption: "test caption"})
```

This creates an Article without errors, but if I call:

```rb
article.image
```

I get:

```rb
=> nil
```

If I type in console:

```rb
article = Article.new(title: "test", content: "test", author: "test")
article.build_image(image: "test.jpg")
```

I get:

```rb
=> Validation failed: Image image can't be blank
```

Any help greatly appreciated, I'm very confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's necessary to supply the attachment itself, rather than just the path. As an example,

```
i = Image.new(
  :image => File.join(Rails.root, "test.jpg")
)
i.image

# =>
```

but

```
i = Image.new(
  :image => File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "test.jpg"))
)
i.image

# => /uploads/tmp/20120427-2155-1316-5181/test.jpg
```

It's not necessary to use `File.open` when saving using Multipart POST, though.